# Is "at which" unnecessary or redundant in "the age at which you now are"?

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy

I asked some of my friends a question - *Do you like being the age at which you now are?* But I found it a bit weird after asking.

Is this sentence redundant? Should I just say “*Do you like being the age you are now*” instead?

Comment: The example with "at which" is fine here.  It's perfectly correct. You can rephrase it as you suggest. That's fine too.

Comment: If I wanted to keep ***at***, I think I'd bin ***which*** (and fix the non-idiomatic final sequence) - *"Do you like being **at** the age you **are now**?"* But I can't see why I'd want to keep ***at*** anyway,

Comment: @FumbleFingers I already said that, so why repeat it?

Comment: My point was the same as DrMoishe Pippik's point, not yours! *I wouldn't include **at** [which]*.

Answer (score 1):

Though grammatically correct, adding at which *seems* a bit awkward. To back up that perception, [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=age%20you%20are%2Cage%20at%20which%20you%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showed the shorter version to be used more than 100 times more frequently -- but there *are* some citations using "age at which you are". There are none for "age at which you now", and NGRAM has a five-word limit.

Answer (score 0):

**To be at an age**

- She is at an age when or where arguing with parents is commonplace.

**Do you like being at the age you are now?**